# sed for weather for conky

Tags: perl, awk, sed, conky

```
$ inxi -xxxw
Weather:   Conditions: 23 F (-5 C) - Scattered Clouds Wind: From the West at 15 MPH Humidity: 53%
       Pressure: 29.89 in (1012 mb) Wind Chill: 10 F (-12 C) 
       Location: Chicago IL (USA) Altitude: 184 ft
       Time: November 17, 11:25 AM CST (America/Chicago) Observation Time: November 17, 10:53 AM CST
```

1) The above is a terminal command for local weather.

```
$ inxi -xxxw | sed 's/Co/\nCo/;s/Wind:/\nWind:/;s/Hu/\nHu/;s/Pr/\nPr/;s/Wind Chill/\nWind Chill/;s/Loc/\nLoc/;s/Al/\nAl/;s/Time:/\nTime:/;s/Ob/\nOb/'|sed -r 's/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g'|sed '/^[ \t]/d'
Weather:   
Conditions: 23 F (-5 C) - Scattered Clouds 
Wind: From the West at 15 MPH 
Humidity: 53%
Pressure: 29.89 in (1012 mb) 
Wind Chill: 10 F (-12 C) 
Location: Chicago IL (USA) 
Altitude: 184 ft
Time: November 17, 11:31 AM CST (America/Chicago) 
Observation Time: November 17, 10:53 AM CST
```

2) The above is the command with sed for vertical display in conky.

```
12Weather:   12
Conditions 28 F (-2 C) - Mostly Cloudy 12Wind From the WNW at 14 MPH 12
Humidity 69%
12           12
Pressure 29.94 in (1014 mb) 12
Wind Chill 17 F (-8 C)
```

3) The above is the result of the vertical display command (2) ran in a conky.conf file.

Question is how do I get (3) to look like (2) ?     Just can't get the info for this here.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's a quick sed tip: the `&` variable contains the whole matched string.  All of your `s/Co/\nCo/;` type replacements can be simplified to `s/Co/\n&/;`

Comment: why do you want that output displayed in 3? It looks to be missing data. What is with the `12`s scattered around? Be happy that you can get the output you want using #2. Spend your time trying to figure out how to use that for your final requirement. Good luck.

Comment: When I run the command in (2) in a conky.conf I should get the same output.  I get bad output shown in (3).  I want (2) to display in conky.   If you have a conky running try it.    THX.

Answer (score 0):

Probably conky's config parser "eats" a lot of your special characters in the `sed` command. If really that's the problem, you could go for a sed interpreter script instead.

Create the file `/usr/local/bin/inxi2conky` with the contents below and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf                          
# Remove leading whitespace
s/^[ \t]+//
# Insert linefeeds in front of keys
s/Co|Wind|Hu|Pr|Loc|Al|^Time|Ob/\n&/g
# Remove resulting extra leading linefeeds
s/^\n//
```

And then add this to `conky.conf`:

```
inxi -xxxw | /usr/local/bin/inxi2conky
```

Comment: Still seeing the bad output in the conky display as in (3) above.

Comment: As I mentioned this is just a possible cause of the problem. You could try putting the entire pipeline into a shell script and call that from conky.